# USB/IP on Win10 1903 "failed to open usb id database"

Tags: linux, windows-10, networking, usb

I am attempting to get USB/IP to work with a Windows client and Linux server (that is to say, devices are physically plugged into Linux machine).

I am able to run a `usbip.exe list -r [host]` command from the Windows machine and successfully get a list of bound devices on the Linux machine, however the list is prepended with the error `usbip: error: failed to open usb id database` and the devices show up as `unknown vendor : unknown product`.

Attempting to attach the device results in:

```
usbip: error: recv op_common
usbip: error: read_devbuf: failed to read: err: 0x6
```

However, this results whether or not any devices are bound, so I believe this error may be derived from the database error.

I have attempted to run the command in both a non-Administrator and Administrator PowerShell window. I have also tried searching through the source code to find where it's looking for the database file, but I could not locate a path.

Answer (score 0):

Copy Linux `/usr/share/hwdata/usb.ids` to Windows usbip documents. File `usb.ids` contains USB device types.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a year old, but I just encountered the same issue using usbip-win v0.3.0 on Windows 10. It seems that the usb.ids file is missing from the distribution version on github, but is present in older versions. To correct this issue, download usb.ids from a previous version of usbip-win, or download the file from linux-usb.org, then place the missing usb.ids in the same folder as usbip.exe.

http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids